# Query optimization. Query without NOT IN

Tags: mysql, subquery, query-optimization

I have a table with id and code entries. Codes are unique, but id is the primary key.

```
ID Code 
1 ABC1234T
2 ABC6789Y
3 ABC9999A
4 QAZ1234G
5 QAZ6574U
6 QAZ9999A
7 TRE1234Y
8 REW1234U
```

I need to find prefixes (first 3 letters) that don't have *999A entry. In the given example it'll be TRE and REW. My query is slow, it takes 17 seconds to run on ~9000 records. I understand it's mostly because I'm using NOT IN and subquery. Could anyone give me some ideas how to optimize it?

```
SELECT distinct LEFT(newcode, 3) as codeprefix FROM diatcode where (LEFT(newcode, 3)) NOT in (select DISTINCT LEFT(newcode, 3) from diatcode where newcode like '___9999A' ) order by newcode
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a left join and then filter based on null values. It avoids the subquery, but I am not sure that this is the fastest solution.

```
SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(d1.newcode, 3) as codeprefix
FROM diatcode d1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(d2.newcode, 3) as codeprefix
  FROM diatcode d2
  WHERE d2.newcode LIKE '___9999A') t2
ON LEFT(d1.newcode, 3)=t2.codeprefix
WHERE t2.codeprefix IS NULL;
```

Comment: Thank you! It took 0.2 seconds this time.

Comment: Then at least a fast solution :) thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Although lp_'s solution is perfectly OK, I'd personally go for the much more readable syntax of `WHERE NOT EXISTS()`

```
SELECT distinct LEFT(d1.newcode, 3) as codeprefix 
  FROM diatcode d1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
                      FROM diatcode d2
                     WHERE d2.newcode = LEFT(d1.newcode, 3) + '9999A' )
```

Should be similarly fast, if not faster, especially if there is a unique index/constraint on the `newcode` column.

PS: your original query had ORDER BY newcode while in fact said field is not part of the resultset. I presume you wanted to add `ORDER BY Left(d1.newcode, 3)`